# VS2010 Ldap compile error asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, authentication, ldap

I am new to C# programming. I have a Ldap login code written with VS2013. I have to reuse this code in a new project written VS2010. But i am trying to rebuild the Ldap login code with VS2010 its throwing error:

**'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.CreateIdentity()' is not supported by the language**

I am tried to find an equivalent code for VS2010, but I couldn't. Please suggest for it.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to Asp.Net Identity would be the [SimpleMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider(v=vs.111).aspx) and [SimpleRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simpleroleprovider(v=vs.111).aspx), introduced way back in VS2010 SP1.

Since `UserManagerExtensions.CreateIdentity()` generates a new `ClaimsIdentity` for the user, your closest relative would be `SimpleRoleProvider.CreateRole`.

You're going to find a lot of other places where you won't have a direct port from Asp.Net Identity functionality to the old providers, so it's going to be a tough process rolling everything back...